# Configure ReSharper only to recommend `var` for non-primitive types?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide, resharper

I'm searching for the equivalent to [VS `csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2017#implicit-and-explicit-types) option.

For example, I would like to get a recommendation to use `var` for the following line:

```
object foo = new object();
```

But I would like ReSharper to approve the following line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 0x2a; i++)
```

(How) can I achieve this?

Comment: I dont think you can, however if you head over to the resharper forums you might be able to request the feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only options to select are:

Options -> Code Inspection -> Inspection Severity
[image: screenshot]
If you uncheck the built-in types, then

`for (int i = 0; i < 0x2a; i++)`

would give no warning. But like it says all built-in Types would stop to give a warning.

So `string str = "";` would also give no warning.

But maybe the [Resharper Forum](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community) can help you

Comment: Thank you, this option was exactly what I was searching for!